# Two divs into another div, both with variable size

Tags: css, html

So basically I want to have two divs in another div, and the inner divs should take all the available space. While I searching for a solution I found many solutions to this problems but I couldn't apply any to my problem because all solutions had in common that one of the inner divs had a fixed size. This is not the case in my problem.

**Edit:**
I want to point out that both the content of div a and b is loaded dynamically. So I cant set a fixed size for any of them.

So lets get this accurate:
I have a div "main"
This div contains a div "a" and another div "b" below 'a'.
Div 'a' is the more important div so it should always display all its content and take up as many size as it needs to show its content. Since the content is variable i set 'a' on auto.
So far so good.

Now I have a problem with setting the size of b. It should take all the remaining available space, and in case thats not enough to show all its content it should show a scrollbar.

Is this possible with plain html/css?

Heres a link that roughly shows the problem - copying the real code into fiddler would be to difficult cause of to many extern librarys used etc.
The text should obviously stay inside the borders of the main div.
Also all the text is just a placeholder, as it later will be filled automatically

Here's the link
http://jsfiddle.net/WH64v/5/

Here's the Code

```
    <body>
    <div style="width:300px; height:300px; border-style: solid;">
        <div style="border-style: solid; height: auto">
            hello1 <br>
            hello2
        </div>

        <div style="overflow: auto">
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            hello3 <br>
            end
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you kindly post some code please?

Comment: Yes post on a jsfiddle-like please so we can review and edit it. If your main div has a fixed height, setting `.b { overflow-y:auto; height:100%; }` should be close to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

**solution 1 using scroll bar**  **[WITH FIXED HEIGHT]**

```
.main{
  height:300px;/*whatever height you want for main... this height is eual to the summation of the heights of a and the portion of b you want to make visible at first */
  overflow:auto;/*it will bring scro bar if main requires */
}
.a{
   height:auto;
 }
```

**solution 2 without scroll bar(better approach)::**  **[WITH OUT FIXED HEIGHT]**

```
.main{
  height:auto;/*it will take the height as summation of both a and b automatically */
  overflow:hidden;/*very important */
}
.a{
   height:auto;
 }
.b{
   height:auto;
 }
```

here is your fiddle:: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3ubG8/)**  **[WITH OUT FIXED HEIGHT]**

**EDIT 1 ::**

here is your code : **[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bb7H7/)**  **[WITH FIXED HEIGHT]**

**EDIT 2 ::** your conditions are main's height is fixed but a's height is variable and you want scroll bar only for b then you must have a fixed height for b so change your code  to

```
.main{
  overflow:hidden;   
  width:300px; border-style: solid;height:300px;
}
.a{
   height:auto;border-style: solid;
}

.b{
  overflow: auto;
  height:250px

}
```

here is your 3 rd FIDDLE:: **[ONLY SCROLL B](http://jsfiddle.net/GNSnD/)**

**EDIT 3:** you must need to fix the height of **`b`** somehow so that b can understand after which limit it will introduce the scroll bar.you cant make b with a variable height,because then it will get confuse when to introduce that scroll bar.so you must specify a height for **`b`**

Comment: Sadly this didn't help me: solution 2 doesn't work for me since main has to be a fixed size. solution 1 doesn't because I want to show the scrollbar only in the sub div that needs it.

Comment: i think you are missing something..the second solution works fine for me.i have given you the fiddle

Comment: No, you are missing it :) The size of the 'main' div is fixed. It may not be altered.

Comment: i am missing nothing dear.that was shown in solution one.first check what is written..here is the new fiddle check it..i have given you both solution with fix height and without.you should read it first

Comment: is it fine to you now??

Comment: Read my first comment on your answer please: I dont want main do ever show a scrollbar, the scrollbar should be shown only in div 'b'. This is, because div 'a' is more important and should always be visible.

Comment: would you like to have fixed height for div a

Comment: No, I would know a solution if div a had a fixed size, but sadly I can't use it in this case since the content of div 'a' is variable

Comment: As the content of b is also variable I cant set a concrete size for b either.

Comment: somehow u must need to fix b's height directly or indirectly

Answer (score 0):

You have to use table styling for that one.

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; border-style: solid; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="border-style: solid; box-sizing:border-box; width: 100%; display: table-cell;">
            hello1 <br />
            hello2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row; height: 100%;">
        <div style="float: left; overflow: auto; display: table-cell; box-sizing:border-box; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                hello3 <br />
                end
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gBgfe/

Comment: I'm sorry but there is an issue with your solution. If you look closely you will notice that the height is bigger than the width despite the fact that both have been set to 300px. This is because you used 100% as the height of b. If you do this, b height will be 100% of its parent element size (300px). Thats why main issnt 300px anymore - its no b(300) + whatever a is